# Assets Browser makes my file twice bigger

Tags: asset-browser

I'm just testing the new Assets Library feature of Blender 3.0.

Just for the question :

I had an old file (26Mb) that had 280 low-poly humans in a collection.

I marked them all as assets, and cleared the scene.
So now I have an empty file, with my 280 low-poly humans in the Assets Browser.
But the file got bigger : 44Mb, which is almost **twice bigger**.

Does anyone knows why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The file size increase comes from the asset metadata.**

Which upon very empirical testing takes about 64 ko of space on disk per asset.

$64 * 280 = 17 920 ko $

$17920 + 26000 = 43920 ko = 44 Mb $ (roughly)